# Remove White Bars Around Embedded Google Map

Tags: html, css, wordpress, google-maps, iframe

I used the following code to embed a google map at [www.tastysfreshburgersandfries.com/locations](http://www.tastysfreshburgersandfries.com/locations) but there are white bars above and below it and I can't seem to figure out how to remove them. Any help with fixing that would be great.

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3431.7169822552632!2d-81.45959308200993!3d30.670097134060587!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x88e4fee54019994b%3A0xbe6be3a817d34edf!2sTasty&#39;s+Fresh+Burgers+and+Fries!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1476217073308" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

`.wpb_content_element { margin-bottom: 35px}`, you can play with it and also, `.vc_row-has-fill+.vc_row-full-width+.vc_row>.vc_column_container>.vc_column-inner { padding-top: 35px; }` that also needs to be changed.

But I would suggest you to create a **separate class** and apply it instead of messing with existing CSS styles, as I can see its from other framework.

Answer (score 0):

You have padding on the row that has the iframe (it isn't the iframe which generates the white bars). Look this

[image]

I can figure you are using Visual Composer. First do a click on the pencil who is in the upper right corner of the row to see the **Row Settings**.

[image]

Then go to **Design Options** tab, and check what values do you have on the padding section.

[image]